# "Flutter create" command doesn't add support for Android and iOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-create

guys.

When I want to create new Flutter project with the command `flutter create --org com.example.myapp myapp` it only creates `web` folder and not `android` and `ios`  folders. I also tried to create a Flutter project from Android Studio, but it only created `web` folder as well. I don’t know why is that.

When I tried to add support for Android and iOS inside of the project's folder with command
`flutter create --platforms=android,ios .`
I receive the following message:

```
Recreating project ....
Resolving dependencies... 
Got dependencies.
Wrote 0 files.

All done!
You can find general documentation for Flutter at: https://docs.flutter.dev/
Detailed API documentation is available at: https://api.flutter.dev/
If you prefer video documentation, consider: https://www.youtube.com/c/flutterdev

In order to run your application, type:

  $ cd .
  $ flutter run

Your application code is in ./lib/main.dart.
```

but without added support.

`flutter doctor` returns nothing suspicious:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.2, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.2.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

What could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: your flutter create command `flutter create --org com.example.myapp myapp` looks clean. Are you using the latest/beta version on flutter? it might be a new issue with the relese

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
flutter config --enable-android --enable-ios
```